# cannot log on to server 2008 with local user

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

My work computer (name is LAPTOP-45) is on domain WORKDOMAIN.  I created local user PRESENTER to use during presentations.  However, I cannot log on with this user.  When I attempt to log on (using LAPTOP-45\PRESENTER) I receive the error "there are no logon servers available to complete this request"

How can I log on with this local user?

Comment: Why don't you just login to your laptop with your normal domain account?  Cached credentials will allow you to do this even if you are not connected to the domain.

Comment: The purpose of the local user account is to basically "clean up" the desktop for use during presentations w/o having to close all my open programs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the laptop from the AD and adding it again?
Have you tried to elevate the rights of the user? Have you restricted log-in privileges to a type of users?

Comment: I'd rather not remove my laptop from the corporate domain :)

Comment: TiZon was suggesting remove it then re-add it, in case there's something weird with the security/settings/policy cached to the laptop that it's not seeing something properly, not removing it permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, you're doing presentations on a laptop running Server 2008 on a domain...out of curiosity, why? Last time I heard of someone with your issue they had (for reasons I didn't understand) a server install that was acting as one of the domain controllers so they couldn't create a local user.

How did you create the local user? Are you able to user your presenter user when the laptop is connected to the network with the domain controllers available?

The more information you can provide the better.

Comment: The laptop is my primary development environment... hyper-V, etc. I work at a client site disconnected from my companies network (though I can VPN in over a wireless network as needed).  I created the local user via Server Manager.

Comment: If I connect via VPN, then "Switch User" and attempt to log on, I get the error "The username or password is incorrect".